# How to add vote without refresh with vue.js?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I have a problem when I try to vote, because i need to refresh page so that vote appears. Any suggestion how can I make my vote appear in my view without refresh?
In my view i foreach comments :

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    <div class="comment_list">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                <div class="user_profile_image {{ isset($comment->user->personal_user) ? 'bg_blue' : 'bg_green'}}">
                    @if(isset($comment->user->avatar) && $comment->user->avatar != '')
                        <div class="profile-image">
                            <img src="{{ avatar_path($comment->user->avatar) }}" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                    @else
                        <div class="profile-image {{ isset($comment->user->personal_user) ? 'bg_blue' : 'bg_green' }}">
                            <img src="{{ home_asset('img/user_icon.png') }}" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                <div class="comments">
                    <div class="post">
                        <span class="post_name">
                            {{ isset($comment->user->personal_user) ? $comment->user->personal_user->first_name .' '.$comment->user->personal_user->last_name : $comment->user->business_user->company_name  }}
                        </span>
                        <span class="post_date"> - {{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($comment->created_at))->diffForHumans() }}
                       </span>
                    </div>
                    <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>

                </div>
                <ul class="comment_buttons">
                    <li @click="downvote({{$comment->id}})" :class="{disabled: downvoted}">
                        {{ $comment->downvotes }}
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li @click="upvote({{$comment->id}})" :class="{disabled: upvoted}" >
                        {{ $comment->upvotes }}
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">REPLY</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">SHARE</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

In routes i have this:

```
Route::post('/blog/article/comment/upvote', 'StandardUser\UserBlogController@upvote');
Route::post('/blog/article/comment/downvote', 'StandardUser\UserBlogController@downvote');
```

In vue.js i have this methods:

```
methods: {
    upvote: function (com_id) {
        var comment_id = {
            comment_id: com_id
        }
        this.$http.post('/blog/article/comment/upvote', comment_id)
            .then(function (response) {

            }, function (response) {

            });
    },
    downvote: function (comment_id) {
        this.$http.post('/blog/article/comment/downvote', comment_id)
            .then(function (response) {

            }, function (response) {

            });
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick reading,

In vue, everything defined in data() is reactive, so you get auto-rendering and dynamic binding for free.

Here is an example, you can adapt it to your case.

https://jsfiddle.net/coligo/49gptnad/

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <ul>
    <template v-for="com in comments">
      <li>
        <button @click="com.votes++">Upvote !</button>
        {{ com.votes }} - {{ com.subject }}
      </li>
    </template>
  </ul>
</div>

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    comments: [
        { votes: 0, subject: 'Yolo'},
    { votes: 0, subject: 'Kierkegaard rocked babe'}
    ]
  },
});
```

More on this : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html, check the docs, Evan You made an awesome work to make it look clear and nice.

Comment: Just as a note, in Vue v2, data must be a function that returns an object, so data() {return { comments[ ] } }

Comment: Huuum not exactly, you must turn data into a function when you create components, which is not the case here. Have a look again : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function